# Change US postal codes (CA) to AP stylebook abbreviations (Calif.) in bibliography (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

My `.bib` file is using US postal codes as abbreviations for US states (CA and MA for California and Massachusetts). For a paper I'm writing, these need to be changed to abbreviations such as `Calif.` and `Mass.` (cf. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations#Table)).

I'd prefer not to change my `.bib` file, but instead include a command in my preamble that says "When the entry `LOCATION` in the `.bib` file has strings such as `, CA`, `, MA`, etc., then substitute these with `, Calif.`, `, Mass.`, etc.". (I've added a comma plus space before the strings to be absolutely certain that it doesn't catch any two-letter strings that aren't US states - not that I know right now what that would be, but just in case).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lehiste1970,
    AUTHOR = "Ilse Lehiste",
    TITLE = "Suprasegmentals",
    YEAR = "1970",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge, MA",
    PUBLISHER = "The M.I.T. Press"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{lehiste1970}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

This should read

> Lehiste, Ilse (1970). *Suprasegmentals*. Cambridge, Mass.: The M.I.T. Press.

Comment: Does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74920/abbreviating-text-within-a-reference/99426#99426

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I'd prefer to have a command in the preamble in my ``.tex`` file that I can simply comment out whenever I don't need it. All my other ``biblatex`` tweaks are in my preamble too - delving into ``.bst`` files seems a bit too complicated for me.

Comment: You don't need to delve into bst files.  You create several 50-line .bib files with a line for each state, like thus: `@STRING{ak.us = "Alaska"}` in one versus `@STRING{ak.us = "AK"}` in the other, and then you just include the desired one as the first bib file in your list.  The only extra effort is in composing your `LOCATION` fields in your bib file as `LOCATION = "Fairbanks, " # ak.us,`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I didn't fully understand that. But since I know (from previous questions) that it's fully possible to have one command in the ``.tex`` preamble that searches for a specific string in a specific entry in the ``.bib`` file and then replaces that string with another string, I'd prefer to go with such an approach (which in the end seems like an easier solution).

Comment: Biber can do regex replacements; but surely a regex for this problem would be huge.

Comment: @egreg I would only start with ``CA`` and ``MA``, and add others as they appear in my bibliography (I don't think there are too many of them). Is there a simpler solution, though (Steven's suggestion doesn't strike me as a simpler one)?

Comment: Just use biblatex+biber's `\DeclareSourcemap` feature with one regexp map per state which you need to change. Someone will certainly show you how if you can't work it out from the docs.

Comment: @PLK I think the bigger problem is that I don't really know how to use ``regex``. I have a couple of ``DeclareSourcemap`` commands in my premable with some ``regex`` stuff in them, but they're much too complicated for me to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lehiste1970,
    AUTHOR = "Ilse Lehiste",
    TITLE = "Suprasegmentals",
    YEAR = "1970",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge, MA",
    PUBLISHER = "The M.I.T. Press"}
@BOOK{mehiste1970,
    AUTHOR = "Ilse Mehiste",
    TITLE = "Suprasegmentals",
    YEAR = "1970",
    LOCATION = "San Francisco, CA",
    PUBLISHER = "The California Press"}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=location,
        match=\regexp{,\s*(MA|CA)},
        replace=\regexp{,~\\State\{$1\}}]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\def\State#1{\csname State#1\endcsname}
\def\StateMA{Mass.}
\def\StateCA{Calif.}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Instead of replacing `MA` with `Mass.` I think it's better to replace it with `\State{MA}`, so that a definition can be given (and modified at will).

[image]

Comment: It works, but it undoes the effect of another ``DeclareSourcemap`` that PLK gave me here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95378/9077 ... I cannot do both at the same time?

Comment: @Sverre I think I read somwhere `\DeclareSourcemap{...}` may only be used once, so just put the two `\maps{...}` commands into the same `\DeclareSourcemap{...}`.

Comment: @moewe It worked when I put the two ``\step`` commands under ``\maps\map{...}`` - otherwise it didn't work.