# Translate content in fields in bibliography entries (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, xetex, fontspec

I have in the `@thesis` entries in my `.bib` file the names of institutions and types written in the local language of the thesis. I need to translate these to English. As an example, I need to translate institution names like

> Universitetet i Oslo
>
> Universitetet i Bergen
>
> Høgskolen i Agder

to

> University of Oslo
>
> University of Bergen
>
> Agder University College

and translate type names like

> Hovedoppgave
>
> Hovedfagsavhandling
>
> Masteroppgave

to

> Main subject thesis
>
> Main subject thesis
>
> MA thesis

Based on similar conversions I've done ([Change US postal codes (CA) to AP stylebook abbreviations (Calif.) in bibliography (biblatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142627/change-us-postal-codes-ca-to-ap-stylebook-abbreviations-calif-in-bibliograp)), I have a vague idea what to do, but I don't know how to accurately implement it:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = institution,
          match = , % <- strings like "Universitetet i Oslo", "Universitetet i Bergen"
          replace = ] % <- strings like "University of Oslo", "University of Bergen"
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = type,
          match = , % <- strings like "Hovedoppgave", "Masteroppgave"
          replace = ] % <- strings like "Main subject thesis", "MA thesis"
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

There seems to be a problem doing this when the string I need to replace contains non-ascii characters like `æøå`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@THESIS{aasen2004,
    AUTHOR = "Anita Aasen",
    INSTITUTION = "Universitetet i Oslo",
    TITLE = "Språklig nivellering i Oslo-regionen",
    TYPE = "Hovedfagsoppgave i nordisk språk og litteratur",
    YEAR = "2004",
    SUBTITLE = "Ungdommers valg av språklige varianter i Follo"}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource = type,
          match = {Hovedfagsoppgave i nordisk språk og litteratur}, 
          replace = {Main subject thesis}]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might be delighted to hear that the upcoming version 3 of `biblatex` allows to do exactly that (not automatically though). Then you could use `institution = {Universitetet i Oslo}, institution _translated_english  = {University of Oslo},` and choose whether the original or translated string is shown. I'm sure the `biblatex` maintainers are keen on beta testers, you can find a dev version on http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/experimental/.

Comment: I am delighted to hear that, but I need to wait until it's released through texlive. I have no idea how to install packages manually, and I'm not even going to attempt it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `\regexp`s

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = institution,
          match = \regexp{Universitetet(\s)i},           
          replace = \regexp{University$1of}]
      \step[fieldsource = institution,
        match = \regexp{Høgskolen(\s)i(\s)(.*)},
        replace = \regexp{$3$1University$2College}
      ]
      }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = type,
          match = {Hovedoppgave}, 
          replace = {Main subject thesis} ]
      \step[fieldsource = type,
          match = {Hovedfagsavhandling}
          replace = {Main subject thesis}]
      \step[fieldsource = type,
          match = {Masteroppgave},
          replace = {MA Thesis}]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ``\regexp`` call with ``institution`` will fail with some name at one point, but I can see how to avoid that with your solution to the ``type`` entries - if that situation arises.

Comment: You should also be able to shorten this a bit by matching `{(Hovedoppgave)|(Hovedfagsavhandling)}` instead of the two patterns seperately.

Comment: What does ``%$`` at the end of the ``replace`` lines mean?

Comment: nothing it was a comment to make my editor syntax highlight happy :-). I have removed them now

Comment: @musicman yes, but you have to use `match=\regexp{(Hovedoppgave)|(Hovedfagsavhandling)}`

Comment: I can't get any of these suggestions to work when the original string contains letters like ``æøå`` ...

Comment: Do you include `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`? It works for me.

Comment: I'm using ``XeLaTeX``. I'll see if I can get a MWE up.

Comment: You can try to include `\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}`

Comment: If that implies that my ``.bib`` file is saved in ``utf8`` format, it's not - it's in ``ansi``. All non-ansi characters are coded with their Unicode point, e.g. ``å`` is written as ``{\char"00E5}``. EDIT: I tried adding it to my MWE anyway, but it has no effect.

Comment: That seems command-line like ... ? I'm compiling with TeXworks in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use regex for this. Isn't it easier to define commands for the local strings and put them in different tex-files?For example:

`swedish.tex:`

```
\newcommand*{\strhogskolen}{Høgskolen i Agder}
```

`english.tex:`

```
\newcommand*{\strhogskolen}{Agder University College}
```

In your main-texfile then you just have to include the local file via `\input{swedish}` and use it in the biblatex-file like:

```
@book{somebook,
author={an author},
title={title},
location={\strhogskolen}
}
```

Comment: I agree that using regular expressions doesn't make much sense here, which is why I didn't include ``regex`` in my example. It seems to me that the disadvantage to your suggestion is that I would have to retype all the relevant entries in my ``.bib`` file, and always have to include some other ``.tex`` file to compile a document that refers to these entries.

Comment: @Sverre -- note that you can use `@preamble{ \newcommand{\whatever}{definition goes here} }` in your `.bib` file.  It doesn't solve the re-typing problem, but note that the `\DeclareSourceMap` route requires re-typing and extra typing for each re-map.

Comment: @jon If you look at the linked question for postal codes, ``\DeclareSourceMap`` only needs to be called once, followed by a list of ``\def`` commands that change from the original string to my new string. That doesn't seem to me to involve any more typing that equally many ``\newcommand`` lines in my ``.bib`` file?

Comment: @Sverre -- well, how much more typing is unclear since I haven't tried to implement it. Of course, you could use `\def` in the `@preamble` commands too. It was the regex replace via `\DeclareSourceMap` that adds the extra typing, not the `\def`-ed strings. (Anyway, I was only making the suggestion because of your first comment about the need to include some other `.tex` file: `@preamble` is just a way to keep everything in the `.bib` file...) I am curious about a solution because I care about language localization for city names based on the main language loaded by `babel`/`polyglossia`!