# Can't replace non-ascii characters with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, unicode, biber

This is a follow-up to my question [Translate content in fields in bibliography entries (biblatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174001/translate-content-in-fields-in-bibliography-entries-biblatex), which revealed a problem when trying to replace content in a `.bib` file when that content contain non-ascii characters like `æøå`.

Compiling the following MWE works fine. In this case, the string `def` is replaced by `abc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1968,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "def",
    YEAR = "1968"}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource = title,
          match = {def}, 
          replace = {abc}]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when the string contains non-ascii characters like `æøå`, no output is produced with `LaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1968,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "æøå",
    YEAR = "1968"}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource = title,
          match = {æøå}, 
          replace = {abc}]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The console produces this output (`biblatextest64.tex` being the name of the document) :

```
Failure to make 'biblatextest64.pdf'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber biblatextest64: Command for 'biber biblatextest64' gave return code 256
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
C:\texlive2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:650: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:/texlive2013/texmf-dist/scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl -pdf biblatextest64.tex
```

A pdf is produced when compiling with `XeLaTeX`, but no substitution has taken place:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1968,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "æøå",
    YEAR = "1968"}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource = title,
          match = {æøå}, 
          replace = {abc}]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Move the \DeclareSourcemap before inputenc.

Comment: Sorry I confuse match and replace. Moving \DeclareSoureMap  gets rid off the errors but the match is not replaced.

Comment: Did you try `match = \regexp{æøå}` - this is used to protect special chars in matches.

Comment: @PLK I tried it now, still no substitution is made.

Comment: This was a bug with a NFD unicode boundary. It should be fixed in 1.9 DEV version on SF now (you need to be using biblatex 2.9 with biber 1.9 which is also on SF).

Comment: @PLK Great! I'll wait until the new version is released through TeX live 2014, though (I don't know how to install packages manually).

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the value given to `match` is passed through TeX's expansion mechanism, which is a big problem, but also a help, since we can (also selectively) use `\detokenize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1968,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "æøå",
    YEAR = "1968"}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource = title,
          match = {\detokenize{æøå}},
          replace = {abc}]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is what is written in the `.bcf` file:

```
  <!-- SOURCEMAP -->
  <bcf:sourcemap>
    <bcf:maps datatype="bibtex" level="user">
      <bcf:map>
        <bcf:map_step map_field_source="title" map_match="æøå" map_replace="abc"/>
      </bcf:map>
    </bcf:maps>
```

Without `\detokenize`, the result is

```
  <!-- SOURCEMAP -->
  <bcf:sourcemap>
    <bcf:maps datatype="bibtex" level="user">
      <bcf:map>
        <bcf:map_step map_field_source="title" map_match="\T1\ae \T1\o <E5>" map_replace="abc"/>
      </bcf:map>
    </bcf:maps>
```

So it seems that `\detokenize` works correctly. However, the replacement doesn't take place, which seems to be a problem with Biber.

To wit, I tried the following Perl script (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572156)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, "utf8";
my $string = "æøå";

$string =~ s/æøå/abc/gi; 

print "$string\n";
```

and the result on the terminal was

```
abc
```

Comment: I'm with you until your Perl script. I see that your Perl script works, but how does that relate to ``biber`` and the fact that it doesn't replace the characters?

Comment: @Sverre Biber is programmed in Perl.

Comment: Does that mean there is a solution to this ... ?

Comment: @Sverre Not from me, but probably from Biber's developers.

Comment: In other words a bug report should be made? Presumably here: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues? I'd recommend that someone who knows what they're talking about (i.e. you) submit it rather than me (I would do little more than link to your answer here).

Comment: @Sverre: Make the bug report with your xelatex example. It shows the problem quite clearly (and avoids side effects with inputenc).