# Replace non-ascii characters with biblatex, part 2

Tags: biblatex

This is a follow-up to the question [Can't replace non-ascii characters with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174453/cant-replace-non-ascii-characters-with-biblatex). The aim is to replace certain character strings in `.bib` file entries with other strings.

Compiling the following document now works fine in `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1968,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "xåy",
    YEAR = "1968"}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource = title,
          match = \regexp{xåy}, 
          replace = {abc}]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I use the common macro `\aa` instead of `å`, it fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1968,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "x{\aa}y",
    YEAR = "1968"}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource = title,
          match = \regexp{xåy}, 
          replace = {abc}]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Apart from replacing macros like `\aa` in my `.bib` file with UTF-8 characters like `å`, is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: @JosephWright I've found why it didn't work in my original document. It has something to to with ``\regexp`` and white space. My ``.bib`` file has something like ``foo x{\aa}y bar``, and my ``.sty`` file has ``\regexp{foo x{å}y bar}``. This won't work. Any solution? (I want to use ``\regexp`` because I'm replacing many different strings with one string. e.g. ``\regexp{(foo x{å}y bar)|(bar foo)|(no foo bar)}``.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with spaces in the regex at the LaTeX end. If I edit the `.bcf` file to for example `map_match="foo x\{å\}y bar"` then all is well ('ve escape the `{}` pair to be on the safe side). However, spaces in the regex at the LaTeX end don't get passed on correctly. I'll have to look at that separately!

Comment: Ah! It's deliberate (probably worrying about the spaces that otherwise get added after control sequences). Try `\let\regexp\detokenize` before the source map. If that works for you, should I write up an answer?

Comment: @JosephWright That works! However, I didn't put ``\let\regexp\detokenize`` before ``\DeclareSourcemap``, because that messes up other things I do with ``regexp``. Instead I put it after ``\map{``. Please feel free to add an answer (but remember that it should also answer the original question, not just the stuff we've discussed in the comments here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is looking for exactly what you tell it to; the only thing to bear in mind that conversion to UTF-8 occurs before this process. As such, the BibTeX input

```
title = {x{\aa}y},
```

gets turned into `x{å}y` by Biber and it is that which you need to search/replace for. Its' not the same as when you put

```
title = {xåy}
```

as that has no braces.

As the BibTeX database format requires braces around accents, it's probably best to tackle the issue at the regex end. Thus something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1968,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "x{\aa}y",
    YEAR = "1968"}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource = title,
          match = \regexp{x{å}y}, 
          replace = {abc}]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

should work correctly.

Comment: I've limited the answer to the specifics about accents/braces: the space part can be covered by a separate question if required.

Comment: In newer versions of `biber`, the non-ascii characters can't be enclosed within curly braces anymore, so it needs to say `match = \regexp{xåy}`.

Comment: But for some strange reason, some non-ascii characters still need to be enclosed by curly braces, such as the character `æ`.